# Preventing ANSI Escape Characters in Keyboard Input in C

Tags: c, string, user-input, stdin, ansi-escape

I have a C program that asks the user for their name with a bit of code that reads from stdin on a while loop (until enter is pressed).
I am making sure the user can only enter ASCII values from 32 to 126.

The problem is when I press my arrow (cursor) keys, or something like PAGE_DOWN or other...
I end up having the ANSI escape sequence printed to the terminal ([A, [6~, etc.).

Here is the section of code.

```
char name[6];
char c;
uint8_t i = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    if (c == 127 || c == 8) {   // Checks if backspace or del is pressed
        i--;
        name[i] = ' ';
    } else if (c >= 32 && c <= 126) {   // Only legal key presses please!
        name[i] = c;
        i++;
    } else {

    }

    if ((c >= 32 && c <= 126) || c == 127 || c == 8) {
        printf_P(PSTR("%c"), c);
    }
}
name[5] = '\0';
move_cursor(15, 18);
printf_P(PSTR("%s"), name);
```

I have certainly chosen to ignore ASCII values outside the 32 to 126 range, so what is the cause of this? Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: provide a MCVE _https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve_

Comment: @CIsForCookies Thanks! I've added the appropriate snipped but I am coding for a terminal listening on a serial com port, so the code is a bit different for regular stdout.

Comment: If it's an assignment, leave user's terminal alone. If you want better UX for a production program, use GNU readline or a similar library instead of stdio.

Comment: In other news, don't use magic numbers like 126 or 8 or 32. C has character literals, use these instead.

Comment: Don't worry, the assignment won't mark code quality. Only looks at features implemented. See, we're making the game of snake on a AVR microcontroller and an LED matrix. Sending info back and forth between the user's terminal is useful for displaying other info.

Comment: If this is hardware-specific, yor software  can just recognise a few escape sequences specific to keys present on that hardware and implement commands corresponding to these keys.

Comment: You could try libreadline -- it handles ESC-sequences for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works as expected. With terminal emulations of the VT100-family, a keypress to cursor-up for example sends the following sequence to your application:

```
<ESC>[A
```

Now, the ESC (0x1b) is what gets stripped, since it is out of your valid range. But the other characters are perfectly valid.

So, to also strip these, your program has to recognize terminal escape codes; an easy rule is to remove all characters from the escape to the next letter. This will not catch all terminal escape sequences, but for the most common it will do.

Here you can review a [list of common terminal control escape sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm)

Comment: I'll give it a go! When you say "This will not catch all terminal escape sequences", is this because some are different lengths? For example most are of the form "[X" but page down is "[6~"?

Comment: @TristanBatchler Different lenghts is no problem, since you strip all up to the next letter (not digit!), but if there are letters before the end of the sequence it will not strip enough. But you will rarely encounter one of these

Comment: Fantastic! I've just begun trying what you suggested and it's already looking good. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @ctx: Make that *"remove (ignore) all characters from the escape to the next uppercase letter `A`-`Z`, lowercase letter `a`-`z`, or `~`"*, and it basically covers keyboard input in POSIXy systems.

Comment: Link is offline, but archive.org still has it: https://web.archive.org/web/20200122052321/http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm

Answer (score 0):

The posted code does not contain certain key information.

To make this functionality work, the code needs to modify the 'mode' of the communication with the terminal.

The normal 'mode' is 'cooked' where the key strokes are echo'd to the terminal and key strokes like 'backspace' are handled by the terminal driver.

To enable the desired functionality, the 'mode' must be 'raw' and 'echo' must be turned OFF.